# What is the KDE equivalent of a Nautilus script?

Tags: gnome, kde

I have just begun to use KDE, and I can't find any info about the KDE equivalent of a Nautilus script. What I need to be able to do is select some files, right click, and apply a number of commands to all of them, as with a Nautilus script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the KDE world, the default File browser is Dolphin (instead of Nautilus), and the scripts (like in Nautilus) it has called Service menu.

See [here](http://kde-apps.org/?xcontentmode=287) for the official list of them.

Answer (score 2):

those are now here: https://store.kde.org/browse/cat/102/ord/latest

but heavily censored, and may or may not work at any given time.